# How to prevent the console browser from opening when launching the server ?

Tags: h2

When launching java -cp h2-1.3.161.jar org.h2.tools.Server it always opens the console in a browser.

How can I prevent that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like java -cp h2-1.3.161.jar org.h2.tools.Server -tcp -web will do the trick.